# How do i cycle through an array and compare each element in that array to every element in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, space

I am very unfamiliar with python and have been tasked with doing some python coding. I need to compare every element in an array 't' to all elements in an array 'r'. My goal is to find if any elements (scalar) in the 't' array are isolated by a minimum of 200 units from ALL scalars in the 'r' array; that is, if they are separated by 200 units or more from all elements in the 'r' array I want to flag them as 'isolated'.

I imagine this is a fairly simple operation, I am just unfamiliar with the structure. Thank you in advance for taking the time to help me. Much appreciated!

If it is of any help, here is the code being used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
from math import sqrt

from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

omega_m = 0.3
omega_lam = 0.7
H0 = 70.    # Hubble parameter at z=0, km/s/Mpc
c_kms = 299792.458 # speed of light, km/s
dH = c_kms / H0          # Hubble distance, Mpc


def inv_efunc(z):
""" Used to calculate the comoving distance to object at redshift
z. Eqn 14 from Hogg, astro-ph/9905116."""
return 1. / sqrt(omega_m * (1. + z)**3 + omega_lam)

# read in data from file
r = np.genfromtxt('coma_vicinity.dat', dtype=None, skip_header=0,
              names='ra,dec,cz,r,g,z,rp',
              usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5))

# Calculate the comoving distance corresponding to each object's             
redshift
dist = np.array([dH * integrate.quad(inv_efunc, 0, cz)[0] for cz in     
r['cz']])

c1 = SkyCoord('12h59m48.7s','+27d58m05s',frame='icrs')
c2 = SkyCoord(r['ra']*u.deg,r['dec']*u.deg,frame='icrs')
sep = c1.separation(c2)

r['rp'] = sep.radian*dist

t = np.genfromtxt('UDGs.csv',dtype=None, skip_header=0,names='nm,ra,dec',usecols=(1,2,3))
```

Comment: I haven't fully read through but `itertools.product(t, r)` is a common way of achieving your question.

Comment: I am trying to use the itertools package, but I don't see how a product will help me find a 200 unit minimum difference (that seems more like subtraction). Any advice here? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what data is in `r` and `t` and what your expected output is?

Comment: Read about [Python Sets](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Sets), or  [python3_sets](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_sets_frozensets.php)